# If $0<x<1$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\geq 4$.

Tags: proof-writing

I've been working on this problem for a while and just can't quite seem to figure out what to do. I'm not so much looking for a solution as I am a push in the right direction. I was able to show that

$0<x(1-x)<1$

but this is where I started having trouble. We are not supposed to use calculus for this and, if possible, I would like to avoid using the formula for the maximum of a quadratic. I understand that if I can show that

$x(1-x)<\frac {1}{4}$

then it would be easy as I can then provide an instance where

$x(1-x)=\frac {1}{4}$

and thus

$x(1-x) \leq \frac {1}{4}$

Comment: $x(1-x)=(\frac12+(x-\frac12))\cdot(\frac12-(x-\frac12))=\frac14-(x-\frac12)^2\le\frac14$

Comment: You say not to use calculus. Do limits count as calculus here?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I must have skimmed over that. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  Let $x=\frac 12 + r$.  That would mean $1-x= \frac 12 -r$.  So you need to prov that $\frac 1{x(1-x)}= \frac 1{(\frac 12-r)(\frac 12 + r)}= \frac 1{\frac 14 - r^2} \ge 4$.  Which as $0 < x(1-x) = (\frac 12-r)(\frac 12 +r) = \frac 14 -r^2 \le \frac 14$ is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$x=\frac{1}{2}$ is the only value $x\in (0,1)$ such that $x(1-x)=\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

If $0<x<1$, then $x(1-x)>0$. So the inequality you are looking at is equivalent to
$$x(1-x)\geq \frac{1}{4}$$
Note that $x(1-x)$ is a parabola. The zeroes of this parabola are at $x=0$ and $x=1$, and its vertex (the "tip" of the curve) is right in the middle of them. What is its vertex?

[image: the parabola x(1-x)]

Answer (score 0):

If $0<x<1$ then also $0<1-x<1$. So
$$\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\ge4\iff 4x(1-x)\le 1 \iff 4x^2-4x+1\ge 0$$

Now, can you solve this last problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using AM-GM:

$$\sqrt{x(1-x)} \leq \frac{x+1-x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Squaring and flipping the inequality gives:

$$\frac{1}{x(1-x)} \geq 4$$